# How to use BehaviorSubject in nx module federation?

Tags: angular, angular-module-federation

I have this module federation workspace

```
apps
-- host
---- src
------ app
-------- app.component.ts
-- main
---- src
------ app
-------- app.component.ts
libs
-- components
---- menu
------ src
-------- lib
---------- menu.component.ts
-- services
---- src
------ lib
-------- global.service.ts
```

global.service.ts

```js
items$ = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

setMenuItems(items: any[]): void {
    this.items$.next(buttons);
}
```

menu.component.ts

```js
items: any[];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.globalService.items$.subscribe((result) => {
        this.items = result;
    });
}
```

host app - app.component.ts

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.globalService.setMenuItems([1, 2, 3]); // this works
}
```

main app - app.component.ts

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.globalService.setMenuItems([1, 2, 3]); // this not works
}
```

I can't use global service in my main app.
This is the command I use to run the project: `nx serve host--devRemotes="main"`

Comment: What is the error, please?

Answer (score 0):

That might be because you're not coding reactively.

Try this instead.

```js
@Component(...)
export class MenuComponent {
  items$ = this.globalService.items$.asObservable();

  constructor(private globalService: GlobalService) {
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async" class="menu-item">{{ item }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That did not work

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: Ok. I will create a stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Do you use injectable decorator in service class declaration with provideIn: ‘root’?

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using this